# Mounting a new hard drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I installed a new hard drive that will be used for additional storage only.  I have followed [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive) on Ubuntu pages to partition it, but when I follow the instructions to automatically mount it, I get lost. It tells me to enter a new line in fstab but when I enter the line, there is no way to press enter and confirm.  I also see it says something about using uuid but that link is no help either.

The output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   488397167   244198583+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00034d6c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  1953523711   976760832   83  Linux
```

sudo blkid:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="9EDD-FADC" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="f45d9121-db97-4b97-bdf1-6db2ceaaa3b6" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="f908decc-66cd-41ec-a588-7df965077dea" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="4dfbef06-0f1a-4ec4-a637-0ea911e656ba" TYPE="ext4"
```

cat etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=f45d9121-db97-4b97-bdf1-6db2ceaaa3b6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=9EDD-FADC  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=f908decc-66cd-41ec-a588-7df965077dea none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=4dfbef06-0f1a-4ec4-a637-0ea911e656ba /media/micah/new_hd ext4 defaults 0 2
```

Comment: which filesystem did you use?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#Editing_Ubuntu.27s_filesystem_table try this wiki instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was changing the ownership.  I moved the directory to /home/micah/Media instead of /media/micah/new_hd.  I then entered sudo chown micah:micah /home/micah/Media -R and after a reboot I now have permission to use the hard drive.  One question.  I know I can use the hard drive listed under devices but is there a way to have the "Media" folder show up on the left side of Nautilus just like  "Pictures, Videos"?  Thanks for all your help @girardengo

Comment: i have edit my answer, add `sudo chmod 777 /media/<username>/new_hd` and changing fstab line, from `defaults` to `rw,user,exec`. This may fix permission problems. Your solution did also work.

Comment: Go to the folder you want to link. Either press Ctrl+D or go to the top menu bar and select Bookmarks -> Add Bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

Mounting partition require first mount point. Create a directory where you want to mount the partition of new hdd:

```
sudo mkdir /media/<username>/new_hd
sudo chmod 777 /media/<username>/new_hd
```

(Note that the first time you use the sudo command prompts you to enter your password)

Second step, find the UUID of the partition to mount:

```
sudo blkid
```

read output, and copy the relevant UUID.

Finally, edit `/etc/fstab` (assuming that the filesystem is ext4):

fields in `fstab` are:

```
<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
```

so add this line:

```
UUID=<uuid_new_hd> /media/<username>/new_hd ext4 rw,user,exec 0 2
```

To do that, remember to edit with superuser permission, then using `sudo`:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Note: Gtk-WARNING when execute this command is normal. instead of `gedit` you can use `nano` or `vim` (non-GUI editor).

Check if new line was added, by typing:

```
 cat /etc/fstab
```

Then mounting and checking the partitions typing the following command in terminal:

```
sudo mount -a
```

If everything is ok, this command should not give back any output, and partition the new hd should be mounted.

Type `man fstab` for more help and options, or read [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#Editing_Ubuntu.27s_filesystem_table) as suggested, and type `man sudo` for help with `sudo` command.

Comment: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/media/micah/new_hd’: Permission denied . That's the message I got after trying the first command.

Comment: @user254074 sorry, my mistake. The command must be run with superuser permissions. I edited my answer with the correct command.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.  I am not sure if I am messing something up but after I enter sudo gedit/etc/fstab it opens a text editor and I can't add a new line unless I hit enter.  When I hit enter it gave me this message.  I continued to enter my new line and save and this is what terminal showed through that process.  My HD is still not functional.

Comment: (gedit:26287): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

(gedit:26287): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
micah@micah-desktop:~$ sudo

Comment: micah@micah-desktop:~$ sudo
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user]
            [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-u user] file ...
micah@micah-desktop:~$ sudo mount -a
micah@micah-desktop:~$

Comment: @user254074 I made changes to my answer. Run the commands step by step, gives the output of the command returns an error. Edit your question adding the output of this three commands: `sudo fdisk -l`, `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: I edited my question with the info you requested.

Comment: I guess according to your instructions it is showing that it's mounted but it still appears to not be functional.  It shows up under devices in the file system with an eject option and when I try to drag a file over to it it doesn't transfer.  Maybe the issue is permissions.  When I go to permissions everything is grayed out.  It shows I am not the owner.  I don't know if this is a mounting issue or if there is something else I can do to correct this.

Comment: Should this new directory show up by typing ls in terminal?  Where is this directory located because according to it's address it looks like the directory "media" should be under root thus it would show up when typing ls.  I am still fairly new to this so maybe I have no clue what I am talking about.